# How to find a callback attached to a bbpress hook?

Tags: hooks, bbpress

bbpress has a large number of callbacks attached to various hooks. I am familiar with this feature at the wordpress level but I am unable to locate where bbpress registers a large number of these callbacks. Specifically I would like to change the behaviour of the callback which is triggered via:

```
do_action( 'bbp_template_before_forums_loop' );
```

If someone could help me locate this callback so that I can change the HTML it outputs that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find an attached callback, you normally can just do the following:

```
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['hook_name'], TRUE ) );
```

This should give you back an array of callbacks attached to a hook, ordered by priority (which serves as key).